# Integrals of Jacobi $\vartheta$ functions on the interval $[1,+\infty)$

Tags: calculus, integration, elliptic-integrals, dirichlet-series, theta-functions

I start from the following obvious observation, which is declared to be($q=e^{-\pi x}$):
\begin{aligned}
\int_{1}^{\infty}x\vartheta_2(q)^4\vartheta_4(q)^4
\text{d}x&=\int_{0}^{1}x\vartheta_2(q)^4\vartheta_4(q)^4
\text{d}x\\
&=\frac12\int_{0}^{\infty}x\vartheta_2(q)^4\vartheta_4(q)^4
\text{d}x=\frac14,
\end{aligned}
in which the functional equation $\vartheta_2(e^{-\pi/x})=\sqrt{x}\vartheta_4(e^{-\pi x})$ is used. The last equality is derived from
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{s-1}\vartheta_2(q)^4\vartheta_4(q)^4\text{d}x
=16\frac{\Gamma(s)}{\pi^s}\lambda(s)\eta(s-3).
$$
Then, I am confronted with the new one
$$
\int_{1}^{\infty}\theta_2(q)^4\theta_4(q)^4
\text{d}x=\frac{2G}{\pi^2}.
$$
These two integrals have cousins widely as well. For example, some experiments suggest
\begin{aligned}
&\int_{1}^{\infty}(x^2-1)\vartheta_2
(q)^4\vartheta_3(q)^4
=\frac{8G}{\pi^2}-\frac{14}{\pi^3}\zeta(3),\\
&\int_{1}^{\infty}(1+x)^2
\vartheta_2(q)^2\vartheta_3(q)^4\vartheta_4(q)^4\text{d}x
=\frac{\Gamma\left ( \frac14 \right)^8}{8\pi^6},
\end{aligned}
the integral
$$
\int_{1}^{\infty}
\left [ (x-1)\vartheta_2(q)^4\vartheta_3(q)^2
+2\sqrt{2}x\vartheta_2(q)^3\vartheta_4(q)^3  \right ]\text{d}x
=2-\frac{8G}{\pi^2}
$$
included. By substituting $x=K^\prime(k)/K(k)$, we obtain
\begin{aligned}
&\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} } }
K(k)\left ( K(k)+K^\prime(k) \right )^2\text{d}k
=\frac{\Gamma\left ( \frac14 \right )^8 }{128\pi^2},\\
&\int_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} } }^{1} 
\frac{K(k)^2-K^\prime(k)^2}{k} \text{d}k
=\pi G-\frac{7}{4}\zeta(3),\\
&\int_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} } }^{1} 
\left(\frac{K(k)-K^\prime(k)}{k}+\frac{2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{k}K(k)  }{(1-k^2)^{1/4}}  \right)\text{d}k
=\frac{\pi^2}{2}-2G.
\end{aligned}

---

*Question.* Is there any ways being able to prove the integrals listed above?
*The 2nd Question.* I wonder if it exists similar ones with the interval $[\sqrt{n},+\infty)$, where $n\in\mathbb{Q}_{>0}$.

Answer (score 1):

The methodology to solve those integrals is somewhat complex. Some fair results could be shown first.
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} }K(k)\text{d}k
=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2} }\,_3F_2
\left ( \frac12,\frac12,\frac12;1,\frac32;\frac12 \right ),\\
&\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} }K^\prime(k)\text{d}k
=\frac{\pi^2}{8}+ \frac{\pi}{4 }\,_3F_2
\left ( \frac12,\frac12,\frac12;1,\frac32;-1 \right ),\\
&\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} }\frac{K(k)}{1-k^2}\text{d}k
=\frac{\pi}{2}\,_3F_2
\left ( \frac12,\frac12,\frac12;1,\frac32;-1 \right ),\\
&\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} }\frac{K^\prime(k)}{1-k^2}\text{d}k
=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}\,_3F_2
\left ( \frac12,\frac12,\frac12;1,\frac32;\frac12 \right ),\\
&\begin{aligned}\int_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} } }^1 
\frac{K(k)}{k} \text{d}k
&=\frac{5\pi}{4}\ln(2)-\frac{\pi}{32}\,_4F_3\left ( 1,1,\frac32,\frac32;2,2,2;\frac12 \right )-2G,\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\,_3F_2\left ( \frac14,\frac14,\frac14;1,\frac54;1 \right ) 
+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2} } \Gamma\left ( \frac34 \right )^2
\,_3F_2\left ( \frac14,\frac14,\frac34;1,\frac54;1 \right ) 
-2G,\end{aligned}\\
&\int_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} } }^1 
\frac{K^\prime(k)}{k} \text{d}k
=\frac{\pi}{2}\,_3F_2\left ( \frac14,\frac14,\frac14;1,\frac54;1 \right ) 
-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2} } \Gamma\left ( \frac34 \right )^2
\,_3F_2\left ( \frac14,\frac14,\frac34;1,\frac54;1 \right ),\\
&\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} } } 
\frac{K(k)}{\sqrt{1-k^2} } \text{d}k
=\frac{\pi^2}{8}\,_3F_2\left ( \frac14,\frac14,\frac12;1,1;1 \right ),\\
&\begin{aligned}
\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} } } 
\frac{K(k)}{\sqrt{k}\left ( 1-k^2 \right )^{3/4}  } \text{d}k 
& = \frac{\Gamma\left ( \frac14 \right )^4 }{8\pi\sqrt{2} }- \frac{\pi^2}{4\sqrt{2} }\,_3F_2\left ( \frac14,\frac14,\frac12;1,1;1 \right ),\\
&=\pi\,_3F_2\left ( \frac14,\frac12,\frac12;1,\frac54;-1 \right ),\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{\pi} }{8}\Gamma\left ( \frac14 \right )^2\,_3F_2\left ( \frac14,\frac14,\frac14;\frac34,1;1 \right ),
\end{aligned}\\
&\int_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} } }^{1} 
\frac{K(k)^2}{k}\text{d}k
=\frac{3\pi^2}{8}\ln(2)+\frac{\pi G}{2}
-\frac{7}{4}\zeta(3)-\frac{\pi^2}{128}
\,_5F_4\left ( 1,1,\frac32,\frac32,\frac32;2,2,2,2;1 \right ),\\
&\int_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} } }^{1} 
\frac{K^\prime(k)^2}{k}\text{d}k
=\frac{3\pi^2}{8}\ln(2)-\frac{\pi G}{2}
-\frac{\pi^2}{128}
\,_5F_4\left ( 1,1,\frac32,\frac32,\frac32;2,2,2,2;1 \right ),\\
&\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} } } 
kK(k)K^\prime(k)\left ( K^\prime(k)^2-K(k)^2 \right ) 
\text{d}k=\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}} 
\frac{K(k)^4}{\sqrt{1-k^2} }\text{d}k,\\
&\int_0^1K(k)^2\text{d}k+\int_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} }}^{1} 
\left ( K(k)^2-K^\prime(k)^2 \right )\text{d}k
=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} } \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} }} 
\left ( \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}\left ( 1-k^2 \right )^{1/4}  }  
+\frac{\sqrt{k} }{\left ( 1-k^2 \right )^{3/4} } \right ) K(k)^2
\text{d}k,\\
&\int_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} }}^{1} 
K(k)K^\prime(k)\text{d}k
=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2} } \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} }} 
\left ( \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}\left ( 1-k^2 \right )^{1/4}  }  
-\frac{\sqrt{k} }{\left ( 1-k^2 \right )^{3/4} } \right ) K(k)^2
\text{d}k,\\
&\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} }} 
\frac{K(k)^2}{\sqrt{1-k^2} } \text{d}k
=\frac{\pi^3}{16}\,_4F_3\left ( \frac12,\frac12,\frac12,\frac12;1,1,1;1 \right ),\\
&\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2} } \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} }} 
\frac{K(k)^3}{\sqrt{k} \left ( 1-k^2 \right )^{3/4} }
\text{d}k-\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} }} kK(k)^3\text{d}k
=\frac{\Gamma\left ( \frac14 \right )^8 }{512\pi^2} 
-\frac{3\pi^2}{8}\,_3F_2\left ( \frac12,\frac12,\frac12;\frac54,\frac54;1 \right ).
\end{align}